# Sorting an array from lowest to greatest FORTRAN

Tags: arrays, sorting, fortran, fortran90

So I'm in my first year of the carrer and I've gotten stuck in an assignment, we need to read an array and then give it sorted from lowest to highest, so my approach was to create another array and star giving it the first array's minimum value and go on.
Little me I did it, I made a code so that I could read the array's values and assign the lowest to a separate value called minimo.
However I'm stuck right there, I can assign that lowest value to the first value of my new sorted array, but when checking again for the lowest value it would of course tell me the same number, so I thought that maybe after giving me the lowest value I could remove it from the original array and check again for the lowest value, but I literally don't know where to start, or even if this is the optimal way to do it, or even a possible one. 
Here's the code.

```
PROGRAM hello
IMPLICIT NONE
integer, dimension(1000) :: vector, v_ascendente, v_descendente
integer :: v_size, i, j, minimo = 1000000

print*, "Cuantos numeros introducira"
read*, v_size
print*, "Introduzca los", v_size, "numeros del vector separandolos por ENTER"

do i=1, v_size
    read*, vector(i)
end do

do j=1, v_size
    do i=1, v_size
        minimo = min(minimo, vector(i))
    end do
    print*, "minimo = ", minimo
    v_ascendente(j) = minimo
end do
END PROGRAM
```

You guys got any idea on another way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad: there's a wealth of well-known sorting algorithms which we can't cover here.  If you are trying to implement a particular one and get stuck doing it, then please revise the question with focus there.  Of course, if you are really wanting to do something with this current approach, then it'll be better to remove the "optimal way" parts.

Comment: In terms of the problem of how to remove a particular element from an array, there are questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21397197/3157076) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36561018/3157076) covering that.  If that's really your problem, then you can perhaps rephrase away from being a "sorting" question?

Comment: Your code takes a O(n^2) time complexity. It is not optimal. Please read about merge sort, heap sort or even Quick sort. If you want more faster way to do it and your array value is not too much. You can use Counting Sort all of them are better than your algorithm.

Comment: And many of those well-known algorithms have their Fortran implementations freely available, e.g., https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Shell_sort#Fortran Choose any other in https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_Algorithms

Comment: I think the holding of this question is a little harsh on a new contributor.  While the final question *You guys got any idea on another way to do this?* is indeed rather broad, making a working code which accords with OP's outline design offers some valuable lessons for a Fortran beginner.  And, Backus knows, there are few enough regular contributors on Fortran topics that we should perhaps be reluctant to scare off new ones.

Comment: I largely agree with @HighPerformanceMark's comment about the holding.  Indeed, what you have is a good answer (and one which justifies a little the decision to put on hold) to what the question _could_ be.  If you can edit the question to focus on the problem you have with the array, relegating the _sorting_ aspect to mere motivation, then I'll happily vote to re-open.

Comment: Thank you guys, and sorry for this being a vague and confusing question, I have noticed and will not make the same mistake in the future. I',ve decided to go for the merge method of which I found a great video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzeBrDU-JaY&

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving aside for a moment whether or not this is a good way to sort an array let's answer OP's immediate question concerning how to make the chosen approach work.  This answer uses the intrinsic routines `minval` and `minloc`.  In both cases it uses the optional argument `mask` which governs which elements of an array argument are considered.  For a proper explanation of the functions, and of their arguments, see your favourite Fortran documentation.

First, declare the mask, a logical array of the same size and shape as `vector`

```
  LOGICAL, DIMENSION(v_size) :: mk = .TRUE.
```

Next, repeat the following logic `v_size` times:

- find the smallest element in `vector` which has not been masked off;
- copy that element to the `i`-th location in `v_ascendente`;
- mask off the location of that smallest element so that it is not considered next time around.

Which leads to

```
DO ix = 1, v_size
   v_ascendente(ix) = MINVAL(vector,mk)
   mk(MINLOC(vector,mk)) = .FALSE.
END DO
```

Note that this approach avoids entirely the conceptually problematic, and in practice slow, operation of removing elements from arrays.  Yes, I could have demonstrated a code doing that, but it would have made an already slow approach even slower.

Is this a good sorting method ?  Not particularly, but I've seen worse in production code and for short arrays its poor performance won't be noticed.  And it is that performance as the size of the array to sort grows which makes this a poor choice for a general-purpose sort routine.

Which takes us to the issues of *computational complexity* and of sorting in general, which is just about the most studied problem in computer science and software engineering.  And here I agree with the comments made that tackling a wider question such as *What is a good sorting method ?* takes us way beyond what is acceptable here.